# How to destruct a List element that contains three lists, so I can create a list to add to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

What is coming in to the webAPI is this JSON string and becomes deserilized in to this:

```
List<AddAssignMealView> mealtraiDeserializeObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AddAssignMealView>>(mealTrainee);
```

`mealtraiDeserializeObjects` contains five index's one for each day of the week. Inside that specific index is a class that looks like what is below:

```
public class AddAssignMealView
{
    public int TraineeID { get; set; }
    public string DayOfTheWeek { get; set; }
    public List<string> MealTypes { get; set; }
    public List<int> MealID { get; set; }
    public List<string> MealName { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is, be able to create a list of `MealTrainee`(Entity Framework):

```
 public partial class MealTrainee
{
    public int MealTraineeID { get; set; } //Ignore this one due to it being a post
    public int MealID { get; set; }
    public int TraineeID { get; set; }
    public string DayOfTheWeek { get; set; }
    public string MealType { get; set; }
    public string MealName { get; set; }

    public virtual Meal Meal { get; set; }
}
```

So I can be able to use addrange and add the list to the database. I understand how to use zip and combined two list types together if it is a single element. This is different due to it being a list of five elements and each of those five elements containing three lists. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be helpful.

Comment: Your MealTypes, MealID and MealName lists of AddAssignMealView contains the same count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Zip` 2 times to combine values from 3 lists into series of tuples. You can use `SelectMany` to flatten results. For example:

```
var result = mealtraiDeserializeObjects.SelectMany(c =>
    c.MealID.Zip(c.MealName, (id,name) => new {id, name})
    .Zip(c.MealTypes, (prev, type) => new {prev.id, prev.name, type})
    .Select(r => new MealTrainee
    {
        TraineeID = c.TraineeID,
        DayOfTheWeek = c.DayOfTheWeek,
        MealID = r.id,
        MealName = r.name,
        MealType = r.type,
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found. I took it day by day in the sense that the first iteration would be Monday and then the count of meals(Ex:Meal for breakfast, Meal for Lunch) and put them in a count which would be "mealweek". Then I took mealweek and created a new mealtrainee for each count. Then after I made the meal out of the mealtrainee I put it in db.MealTrainees.AddRange and posted all the records.

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(MealTrainee))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostMealTrainee([FromBody] string mealTrainee)
    {
        List<MealTrainee> meals = new List<MealTrainee>();

        using (DbContextTransaction dbContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                List<AddAssignMealView> mealtraiDeserializeObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AddAssignMealView>>(mealTrainee);

                foreach (var mealtraiDeserializeObject in mealtraiDeserializeObjects)
                {
                    var mealWeek = mealtraiDeserializeObject.MealID.Select((m, i) => new
                    {
                        mealtraiDeserializeObject.TraineeID,
                        mealtraiDeserializeObject.DayOfTheWeek,
                        MealID = m,
                        MealTypes = mealtraiDeserializeObject.MealName[i],
                        MealName = mealtraiDeserializeObject.MealTypes[i]
                    }).ToList();

                 var meal = mealWeek.Select(x => new MealTrainee()
                    {
                        DayOfTheWeek = x.DayOfTheWeek,
                        MealID = x.MealID,
                        MealName = x.MealName,
                        MealType = x.MealTypes,
                        TraineeID = x.TraineeID
                    }).ToList();

                    db.MealTrainees.AddRange(meal);
                }

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                return Ok(meals);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                Logger.Log(e);
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```